# Jenkins+MsBuild+Nunit build successfully but without tests

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, jenkins, msbuild

I wrote some tests and add solution that execute it smth like this:

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SmokeTests test = new SmokeTests();
            test.Init();
            test.OneCanLoginMail();
            test.Cleanup();
        }
    }
```

And test example in another project,with Nunit and Selenium WebDriver libraries.

```
[Test]
           public void OneCanLoginMail()
           {
               steps.LoginMail(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
               Assert.True(steps.IsLoggedIn(USERNAME));
           }
```

If i start up project via console everything ok and tests executed as expected.
Then i installed Jenkins,install MSBuild plugin, configured it and succesfully built project.

```
  1>Done Building Project "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\QAlabs\test\StartUp\StartUp.csproj" (build target(s)).

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)
```

But tests are not running.What should i add to view assert log and execute tests?I think i need xml file somewhere smth like maven build file but for .Net

Answer (score 0):

To run your NUnit tests, you have to execute `nunit-console.exe` after your MSBuild step.

[Jenkins batch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DmD8.png)